# Как применить :hover в jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#color4').on('change', function () {
    $("#menu-levoe-menyu ul li a").css("color", $(this).val())
});
```

Нужно не просто применить цвет к ссылкам, а сделать чтобы этот цвет срабатывал только при наведении (:hover).

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так:

```
var color = '#fff'; //цвет по умолчанию
$('#color4').on('change', function () {
    color = $(this).val();
});
$("#menu-levoe-menyu ul li a").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("color", color);
}, function () {
  //а здесь цвет не hover
});
```

Comment: При каждом change будет навешиваться по новому обработчику. Красота!

Comment: @Etki, да согласен, поторопился.

Comment: А как побороть то, что при наведении на одну ссылку цвет меняется для всех?

Comment: вместо $("#menu-levoe-menyu ul li a") -> $(this)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($, linkSelector, colorSourceSelector) { // через замыкание отбиваемся от глобальной видимости и конкретных селекторов
    var color,
        DATA_KEY = 'default-color'; // константы есть, но их пока нет, поэтому просто делаем вид

    $(document).on('change', colorSourceSelector, function () {
        color = $(this).val(); // получаем реальный цвет, на который менять
    });

    $(document).on('hoverin', linkSelector, function () {
        var $this;
        if (!$this.data(DATA_KEY)) { // получаем цвет по умолчанию (и делаем это всего один раз для исключения нештатных ситуаций)
            $this.data(DATA_KEY, $this.css('color'));
        }
        if (color) { // если цвет к этому моменту еще не получен - ничего и не заработает
            $this = $(this);
            $this.css('color', color);
        }
    }).on('hoverout', linkSelector, function () {
        var $this;
        if (color) { // опять же, нет цвета - нет манипуляций
            $this = $(this);
            if ($this.data(DATA_KEY) { // на всякий случай проводим двойную проверку
                $this.color($this.data(DATA_KEY));
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery, '#menu-levoe-menyu ul li a', '#color4'); // запускаем монстра
```

Answer (score -1):

Альтернативный вариант (без адского количества JS)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myColor').on('input', function() {
    $('head').append('<style type="text/css">#container a:hover{color:' + $(this).val() + ' !important;}</style>');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    choose your color
    <input type='color' id='myColor' value='#ff0000'>
  </p>

  <div id='container'>
    <a href='http://google.com'>Go here</a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```